# Сумма двух столбцов со своим условием для каждого за один проход MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица, содержащая следующие поля:
`ID, FirstUserID, SecondUserID, FirstUserCount, SecondUserCount`.
При этом гарантируется, что `FirstUserID <= SecondUserID`.
Нужно: за один проход посчитать сумму Count для пользователя, ID которого мы знаем.
Соответственно, нужно выбирать сначала `FirstUserCount` при условии `FirstUserID <= UserID`, а затем - `SecondUserCount` с условием `FirstUserID > UserID`, где UserID - переданный параметр. Суммировать можно в две различные переменные.
Могу ли я сделать это с помощью одного запроса MySQL?
Если нет, то как оптимально можно это сделать?
UPD: уникальность записи, а также то, что FirstUserID != SecondUserID - гарантируется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Нужно: за один проход посчитать сумму Count для пользователя, ID которого мы знаем.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
           WHEN FirstUserID  = @ID THEN FirstUserCount
           WHEN SecondUserID = @ID THEN SecondUserCount
           END) totalSum
FROM `table`;
```

Запрос даст неверный результат, если существует запись, где FirstUserID = SecondUserID = @ID. Но это ведь несложно исправить...

PS. Но куда как разумнее нормализовать структуру.

Comment: Меня смутило условие равенства в `FirstUserID <= SecondUserID`. Хотел запостить такое же решение.

Comment: Меня оно (если точнее - второе из) тоже было смутило, потому что противоречит фразе `для пользователя, ID которого мы знаем`. Но я посчитал именно эту фразу приоритетной. А для первого - я дал ремарку. Лечится ещё одной секцией WHEN.

Comment: Действительно, ремарку я не заметил.

Comment: Сделать напрямую через API запись, где FirstUserID == SecondUserID не получится, поэтому запрос подходит, благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Так не пойдёт?

```
SELECT
(SELECT SUM(a.FirstUserCount) FROM tbl a WHERE a.FirstUserId = :userId) +
(SELECT SUM(b.SecondUserCount) FROM tbl b WHERE b.SecondUserId = :userId) as total;
```

Либо:

```
SELECT SUM(
  IF(FirstUserID   = :userId, FirstUserCount, 0) + 
  IF(SecondUserID  = :userId, SecondUserCount, 0)
) as total
FROM tbl;
```

Можно добавить `WHERE FirstUserID = :userId OR SecondUserId = :userId` для возможности дальнейшей оптимизации с помощью индексов.

Comment: Это два прохода по таблице

Comment: @Mike, очевидно да. Тем не менее это отвечает на вопрос "Могу ли я сделать это с помощью одного запроса MySQL?"